# Game theory probability

Tags: probability, game-theory

I have a variant of two-finger morra game, where the winner is determined by the parity of the sum of the two numbers thrown, but the amount won or lost is the product of the two numbers. There are two player - Alice and Bob

If Alice plays:

1 finger with probability $p$

2 fingers with probability $1 − p$

Alice wins when outcome is even, and Bob wins if it's odd.

What’s the expected payoff that Bob can achieve if he knows $p$?

How should Alice choose $p$ such that Bob’s payoff is minimized?

Comment: Who wins if the outcome is even/odd?

Comment: I edited the question with the information asked

Comment: Got it, thanks.  Have you tried the usual procedure?  That is, compute Bob's expected payout if he plays  "one" with probability $\psi$ and then maximize in $\psi$?

Comment: No. What's the usual procedure? Does that require a payoff matrix?

Comment: Sure, though it isn't much a matrix.  There are only four possible events.  $(A,B)=(1,1)$, say, occurs with probability $p\psi$ and has payout (to Bob) of $-1$.

Comment: I just wrote it out...it seems to work just fine.  For a fixed $\psi$ write out Bob's expectation $E[\psi]$.  That is linear in $\psi$, so the maximum will be at one or the other endpoint.  Alice's best bet is to level out the curve to achieve equilibrium (so Bob has no preference between $\psi=1$ and $\psi=0$).

Comment: This question should have contained a link to [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758012).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that Alice wins if the sum of the numbers is even. If $a \{1,2\}$ and $b \in \{1,2\}$ are the strategies played by Alice and Bob, respectively. The payoff of Bob is:

$$B(a,b) = \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if}~a = b = 1 \\
2 & \text{if}~a = 1, b = 2 ~\text{or}~ a=2, b=1\\
-4 & \text{if}~a = b = 2 \\
\end{cases}.$$

The expected payoff of Bob knowing $p$ is:

$$\mathbb{E}[B(a, b) | b] =  \begin{cases}
B(1,1)p + B(2,1)(1-p) & \text{if}~b = 1 \\
B(1,2)p + B(2,2)(1-p) & \text{if}~b = 2 
\end{cases}\\=  \begin{cases}
-1p + 2(1-p) & \text{if}~b = 1 \\
2p -4(1-p) & \text{if}~b = 2
\end{cases}\\ = \begin{cases}
2 -3p  & \text{if}~b = 1 \\
6p-4 & \text{if}~b = 2
\end{cases}$$

Bob will choose strategy $b = 1$ if 
$$2-3p > 6p-4 \Rightarrow p<\frac{2}{3}.$$
Of course, he will choose $b=2$ if $p>\frac{2}{3}$. If $p=\frac{2}{3}$, there is no difference between $a$ and $b$.

Now, if $p < \frac{2}{3}$, then Bob plays $b=1$ and his average payoff is $2-3p \in [0, 2]$. On the other hand, if Bob plays $b=2$, then his average payoff is $6p-4 \in [0, 2]$. The minimum of the Bob's payoff is $0$ and it is attained for $p = \frac{2}{3}$. This means that Alice must choose $p = \frac{2}{3}$ to minimize Bob's payoff.

Notice that $p = \frac{2}{3}$ is the **component** of Nash equilibrium for Alice in the space of mixed strategies.

Comment: Very thorough answer. Thanks!

Comment: would Bob's nash equilibrium be the same as Alice's?

Comment: you can try this by yourself. This time the payoff of Alice is $A(a,b) = -B(a,b)$

Comment: @user274065: There's no such things as "Bob's Nash equilibrium" and "Alice's". A Nash equilibrium is a strategy profile that contains a strategy for each player.

Comment: @joriki thanks for clarification. I fixed this in the answer.